# passing array to XML-RPC using R

Tags: arrays, r, api, xml-rpc

I'm trying to send query to API based on the XML-RPC protocol (https://api.sklik.cz/cipisek/). I'm using R with XMLRPC package.

I know how to pass struct as parameter (lists are converted to structs by XMLRPC). However, I cannot figure out how to create and pass an array using function `XMLRPC::xml.rpc`.

Maybe it is worth mentioning that I've already checked that arrays which are returned by API methods are converted to lists by XMLRPC (as well as structs).

I'm looking for any ideas how to pass an array using this package or maybe some other one.

Thanks

Adam